# How I prevent that ant calls ant files twice and calls the files in the correct sequence

Tags: java, ant

I didn't try that until now, but I want to prevent it from the beginning.

I have around 50 projects with an existing build.xml. Now I want to create some ant-scripts (call_needed_files.xml) to call the ant-scripts of the dependent projects - for some projects I need to build some other projects because they need this jar's.

For instance I have this constalation:

```
Workspace
   Project 1
     call_needed_files.xml
     build.xml
   Project 2
     call_needed_files.xml
     build.xml
   Project 3
     call_needed_files.xml
     build.xml
```

Each build.xml has a target "build" and other targets with the same name.

```
<!-- project1/call_needed_files.xml -->
<project name="build project 1">
   <!-- build.xml of the dependent projects -->
   <ant antfile="../project2/call_needed_files.xml">
   <ant antfile="../project3/call_needed_files.xml">

   <!-- build.xml of the own project -->
   <ant antfile="build.xml">
</project> 

<!-- project2/call_needed_files.xml -->
<project name="build project 2">
   <!-- build.xml of the dependent projects -->
   <ant antfile="../project3/call_needed_files.xml">

   <!-- build.xml of the own project -->
   <ant antfile="build.xml">
</project> 

<!-- project3/call_needed_files.xml -->
<project name="build project 3">
   <!-- build.xml of the own project -->
   <ant antfile="build.xml">
</project>
```

So how I can prevent that the build of the project 3 calls twice? ... or is this a "standard feature" of ant?

Is there a possibility to use the "target depends='othertargets'" feature over all this projects so that I do not need to call the projects in the correct sequence?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a possibility to use the "target depends='othertargets'"
>   feature over all this projects so that I do not need to call the
>   projects in the correct sequence?

You guessed it right! Targets defined under "depends" are executed only once.

https://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html

From above URL :

> After A, then B, then C have executed, execution returns to the dependency list of D, which will not call B and A, since they were already called in process of dependency resolution for C and B respectively as dependencies of D

So, you can add those targets in "depends" which are needed to be executed only once.

Comment: Yes, but how could I do that over different ant-scripts? I can't import the scripts because there are many task with the same name so they would be overwritten what I don't want. And I can't write <ant antfile="projectXYZ/build.xml" depends="buildXYZ">. Maybe I think too complicated but please give me a example.